# GraphQL in Jmeter- Variables and Parameters

Tags: json, jmeter, graphql, performance-testing

I want to send variable as float but when I am trying like this

`latitude:"${latitudeValue}"`

where latitudeValue is user defined variable.

and in graphQl query value come as String.
and I get this error

> {"errors":[{"message":"Variable "$latitude" got invalid value
> "41.98240048026275F"; Float cannot represent non numeric value:
> "41.98240048026275F"","locations":[{"line":1,"column":96}],"extensions":{"code":"INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"}},{"message":"Variable
> "$longitude" got invalid value "-102.07540422677995F"; Float
> cannot represent non numeric value:
> "-102.07540422677995F"","locations":[{"line":1,"column":114}],"extensions":{"code":"INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"}}]}

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

There is "Variables" tab in the GraphQL HTTP Request sampler:

[image]

where you can define GraphQL variables like:

```
{
  "id": "${id}"
}
```

and this `${id}` comes from a [User-Defined Variable](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables-Using-User-Defined-Variables)

Once you do this you can use it in the "Query" tab like:

```
query ($id: ID!){
  droid(id: $id){
    id
    name
    friends{
      name
    }
    appearsIn
    primaryFunction
  }
}
```

Without variables:

[image]

With variables:

[image]

More information:

- [GraphQL Queries and Mutations](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/)
- GraphQL server instance used for demo:  [apollographql /
  starwars-server](https://github.com/apollographql/starwars-server)

Comment: Thank you. This is BUG(https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65108). I am trying with variables section only.and query is automatically generated and query is correct.but when I placed variable inside variable section like this "lattitude": "${lattitude}" it takes as string and if I used without quotes like this "lattitude": ${lattitude} it shows error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking at [Bug 65108](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65108) which could be solved by [PR 660](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/pull/660) or [PR 651](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/pull/651)

At the moment you can only insert variable values, that lead to a valid JSON structure.